# Why can't I keyboard-interrupt Python from list(itertools.count())?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, keyboardinterrupt

Something as simple as

```
import itertools
list(itertools.count())
```

doesn't seem to react to keyboard interrupts, i.e. pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.8 (default, Jul 20 2020, 19:59:47) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.count())
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 755703 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
 757204 pts/13   00:00:03 python
 757230 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
$ kill -INT 757204
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 755703 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
 757204 pts/13   00:00:03 python
 757261 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
$ kill -TERM 757204
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 755703 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
 757204 pts/13   00:00:03 python
 757268 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
$ kill -KILL 757204
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 755703 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
 757283 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
[1]+  Killed                  python
$
```

Why?

Comment: Not sure if this [link](https://bugs.python.org/issue31815) helps.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Yes it does, thank you.

Comment: And to complement the issue: internally, Python catches all signals and stashes them to later trigger them *on the main thread* of a Python interpreter (e.g. on linux a signal can be delivered / triggered on any thread). The signal-state gets  checked by the interpreter when running python code, but if the interpreter does not run because we're inside a C function *and* that function never checks for signals, then the signal will just get stashed indefinitely. I would expect that only for signals which are specifically caught, but SIGINT is always caught & re-raised as KeyboardInterrupt.